# How did the Greek aspirates become fricatives?

Tags: greek, soft-question

When I was studying (classical) Greek as an undergrad, we were told that φ θ χ, that is, the Greek aspirate consonants, have the following phonetic values: [f θ χ] and never it was told to us that they should actually be pronounced as [pʰ tʰ kʰ], respectively, which correspond the their phonemic forms /pʰ tʰ kʰ/. What really puts me off is the fact that all complex, idiosyncratic phonological rules that characterize Greek are easier to explain when we use the *true* forms instead of the other ones. Nevertheless, nobody ever spoke about the true forms. Does anybody know how to solve this (potentially historic) conundrum?

Comment: What is the conundrum of which you speak? It's a fact that classical Greek aspirates became fricatives, but facts are not conundrums.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking. It's a sound change, like myriad others; are you asking for a phonetic explanation of why the change happened?

Comment: When you say "undergrad" you mean in university or high school? If you meant university then it is a crime! I can understand that for the sake of making it easier for Greek teenagers they let them read with modern Greek pronounciation, but in a university it is unacceptable.

Comment: It was in university, but the course claims to teach koiné (even though we read mostly Plato and Thucydides), so I suppose either (i) they assume that the change has already taken place and thus it is - according to them - a nonsensical complication to teach how they actually sounded before the hellenistic period, or (ii) they don't have a strong linguistic feeling (which is the most probable, since it was thought to me by theologians, not philologists, nor linguists).

Comment: @eslukas: Ok, I see. It could be worse though e.g. people who attempt to pronounce Anc. Greek with erasmian pronunciation, but end up pronouncing in English (British or American) e.g. kaiai for καί.

Comment: @Midas: I know where you are coming from. Being Italian my mother tongue, every time I hear an Englishman (or an American) pronounce Latin words as if they were English ones a shiver runs down my spine. Not that an Italian pronunciation is correct either, but to my hears it sounds more gentle on the actual phonetics of Latin than the English one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well this sound change took place at different times in different dialects/regions.

Some claim that fricativisation already started in the late 6th/early 5th century BC, but that is controversial (see my reference below). In Laconia there is definite evidence for θ from the 4th century BC where ἀνέσηκε is attested in [inscriptions](http://epigraphy.packhum.org/text/30611?hs=111-120) instead of ἀνέθηκε and σιός instead of θεός. By the 1st century AD this sound change had spread everywhere. If you are interested in the chronology of the Greek sound changes as a whole, this sums it up nicely: ["The Greek language and its speakers"](http://www.palaeolexicon.com/Greek).

> A fricative pronunciation of /pʰ/ is attested in Pamph. phíkati = wíkati ‘twenty’ (4th c. BCE). Spirantization of /tʰ/ also occurs quite early in Laconian: siós = theós ‘god’ (Laconia, 4th c. BCE; cf. Tsakoniansáti ‘daughter’ < Anc. Gk. thugátēr). Other evidence is controversial. p.n. Ephronís for Euphronís (Athens, Hell.) might reflect an assimilation of contiguous homorganic fricatives (/ɸpɸ/ > /ɸɸ/ with simplification to /ɸ/ before a consonant), but careless omission of <u> is more likely. The spelling of <ph> for <th> in worphaía = worthaía ‘(Artemis) Ortheia’ (Laconia, 6th c. BCE), pheôn = theôn ‘god (gen. pl.)’ (Dodona, Hell.) purportedly reflects spirantization of /tʰ/ and /pʰ/, since the fronting /θ/ > /f/ is more natural than /tʰ/ > /pʰ/ (Cockney three [friː]). But a confusion between <Θ> = th and <Φ> = ph may also be behind these examples (Threatte 1980:470-471). However, in Pompeian graffiti (1st c. CE) <f> for <ph> probably mirrors a fricative in the Greek words: Venus Fisica. Arguably, voiceless stops underwent spirantization and voicing in Macedonian: p.n. Boulomága /βuːlomáɣaː/ < /Φuːlomáxaː/ for Phulomákhē, month name Xandikós /ksanðikós/ < /ksanθikós/ for Xanthikós (Hatzopoulos 2007, Méndez Dosuna 2012). Furthermore, these spellings confirm the spirantization of voiced stops in the area. Spellings like gégrappha = gégrapha ‘I have written’ (Caria, 2nd c. BCE), metēllakkhótas = metēllakhótas ‘change (pf. ptc. act. acc. pl. masc.)’ (Caria, 2nd-1st c. BCE) are unlikely to attest to an affricate pronunciation prior to complete fricativization. Lack of spirantization of /tʰ/ and /kʰ/ after /s/ is confirmed by early spellings with <t> and <k> in NW Greece and elsewhere: heléstai = helésthai ‘seize (aor. inf. mid.)’ (Chaleion, 5th c. BCE), páskoi = páskhoi ‘suffer (3 sg. opt. pres.)’ (Olympia, 5th c. BCE). Apparently, /tʰ/ spirantized after /s/ in some areas (Méndez Dosuna 1985:364-366): apodóssai = apodósthai ‘give back (aor. inf. mid.)’ (Olympia, 4th c. BCE). The scantiness of <sp> for <sph>, e.g. aspalísai = asphalísai ‘secure (aor. inf.)’ (Egyptian papyrus, 1st c. CE), also indicates spirantization of /pʰ/ after /s/, which is confirmed by Modern Greek.
>
> Alcorac Alonso Déniz, “Spirantization”, in: Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek Language and Linguistics, Managing Editors Online Edition: First Last. Consulted online on 04 February 2017 http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/2214-448X_eagll_SIM_00000536
> First published online: 2013

Comment: What evidence do you have that it "started already in the 6th century BC?"

Comment: And incidentally, who wrote the linked article on Greek? There's no name there.

Comment: In *Historische Grammatik des Griechischen: Laut- und Formenlehre*, Rix notes that "In einigen Dialekten (kret. el. lak.) ist die Spirantisierung schon früher eingetreten, vor allem bei /tʰ/ θ (lak.: ἀνέσηϰε 4.Jh.v. = att. ἀνέθηϰε) (Rix 1992: 85)."

Comment: @AlexB. : I remember it being dated in the end of the 6th century BC. I changed it to late 6th/early 5th century in my answer. I don't remember every single reference right now, but you can check https://www.jstor.org/stable/293302 . Tucker confirms there is evidence for θ that early and it may be guessed, that the corresponding development applies to φ and χ.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I found Tucker 1969 rather uninformative on this question. He says that in Laconian [tʰ] > [tθ] (ca. 5 BC) > [θ]. **I wonder what evidence there is for Laconian θ [θ]?** On the other hand, Miller 2014 writes that in Laconian θ [tʰ] > θ [θ] (7BC?) > σ [s] (4 BC) and perhaps also in Messenian (5 BC). Since ancient Greek dialects is not my forte, I would like to see actual evidence.

Comment: @AlexB., evidence for a fricative in Laconian is spellings like σιώ for θεώ in Aristophanes -- see Draconis's answer.

Comment: @TKR Well, when I said ancient Greek dialects wasn’t my forte, I didn’t mean to say I knew nothing about them. I’ve already read and re-read, very carefully, the relevant parts in Miller 2014 *Ancient Greek Dialects and Early Authors*; also Tribulato 2010 *Literary Dialects* (in *A Companion to the Ancient Greek Language*); Méndez Dosuna 2007 *The Doric Dialects* (in *A History of Ancient Greek*) and Rex 1992 *Historische Grammatik des Griechischen: Laut- und Formenlehre*.

Comment: @TKR (cont.) Here’s my summary. It is very possible that spirantization happened in Laconian only. A lot of the evidence is unreliable. Alcman:  could be a later editorial intervention. Aristophanes: putting some dialectal inconsistencies and inaccuracies, such forms were either modernized by later grammarians (Méndez Dosuna) and “not fully reliable” (Miller). The biggest problem with such evidence is that **“This writing** [sigma instead of theta – Alex B.] **never features in archaic Laconian inscriptions, and only appears from the fourth century BCE  onwards”** (Tribulato).

Comment: @TRK : This even appears in Herodotus so one might believe that 5th century BC is definite. However, I did think as well that it might be a later transcription error, so this may be a matter of belief rather than a fact. Let me have a deeper look on my materials and see if anyone handles the issue.

Comment: @AlexB. : Apparently dating it back to 6th and 5th century BCE is rather a matter of belief and is controversial. I changed the answer and included a text from a dedicated article in Brills Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek Language and Linguistics which is as recent as 2013.

Comment: @Midas Thanks! Brill's Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek Language and Linguistics is one of my favorite references. So you're in Sweden then? Even though the official link is http://brillonline.nl/entries/encyclopedia-of-ancient-greek-language-and-linguistics/spirantization-SIM_00000536 (behind a paywall), it is freely available on Academia https://www.academia.edu/6202798/Spirantization

Comment: @AlexB.: You're welcome! Ja det stämmer! Yes, that is right. I removed that information from the link though :). I had no idea it was available on academia.

Comment: @AlexB. -- Thanks, that's interesting. I think Tribulato's objection is not very strong, though: Laconians would not have perceived their own [θ] as [s], so they should not necessarily be expected to write it as σ, consistently or at all (except for inscriptions written by foreign scribes). But you've clearly looked into this question in more detail than I have.

Comment: @AlexB., looking some more into the sources you cite, Miller (206) argues that occasional 5C hypercorrect spellings like θαλαθα show that the change to [s] was complete in at least parts of Laconia by then. This suggests that the sigma spellings in inscriptions represent actual [s], which means we have to date the initial spirantization to [θ] to an earlier time.

Comment: @TKR yes, I saw that too. Will write my thoughts on that later today.

Comment: Great explanation and Literaturverweisen (I assume the most understand German, since it is used with quite some nonchalance on this website), I really appreciate it. Please, feel free to continue commentating, the discussion is getting more and more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally accepted nowadays that φ θ χ were pronounced as aspirates in Classical Attic. But this pronunciation didn't last long: as early as Aristophanes θ had become a fricative in some dialects (his stereotypical Spartan characters frequently substituted σ for θ, which was probably an attempt to transcribe a dental fricative using the closest available sound). And in some graffiti from Pompeii, φ was transcribed into Latin with *f* rather than *ph*.

By the first few centuries CE, the transition to fricatives was complete, and has remained in Greek ever since. So until fairly recently, most scholars used the same sounds when talking about Ancient Greek.

We know about the historical aspirates now through a variety of means. But since English distinguishes fricatives and does not distinguish aspirates, Greek learners in America still tend to use this "Erasmian pronunciation". Similarly ε/ει/η, ο/ου/ω are seldom given their reconstructed Attic sound values.

Answer (score 2):

The spriantalisation of the Greek aspirated stops took place at different times in different dialects. “The telltale transcription of φ by Latin f instead of ph is not found until the 1st century AD, and is not usual until the 4th” (Sihler p. 142).

Comment: Gary 2013 concurs, "The aspirated stops became continuants around c1, but most of the examples date to c2 CE and later (ELG i. 137‒211)."

Comment: a nice graph here http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/663/39